# Windows Server 2012 - Possible to make the server run EXE files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2012

I have an unlimited Windows Hosting package on a Windows Server 2012. I wish to run a game server of some game which can run on windows hosts by executing an EXE file (that opens a Console, CMD-like window) - that means, if you want to run a server on your local computer you can simply run this application and use your internet's IP. I want to use my web address as an IP but however my question is: **Can a Windows Server (2012) execute files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With many **BUT**s and **IF**s. First of all nearly all hosting packages differs for purposes. If your hosting not game hosting hosting firm will not allow you using their processing power.

Comment: Okay. I guess that makes sense, and coming to think about it - these game servers do take a lot of power. Nevermind then, it's good to know it's possible though.